# Using the Unit type from MediatR and ReactiveUI (and language-ext)

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui, mediatr, language-ext

I'm using [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) alongside [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui) - and both of them have the `Unit` type, and seems like they *don't like each other*:

Everytime both namespace are imported (`MediatR` and `System.Reactive`), I need to use `using` to distinguish between them two (normally `Unit` from `System.Reactive` is used - since it's baked into `ReactiveUI`)

May I know, is there any approach other than this (and inserting fully qualified name, which is kinda verbose)?

```cs
using MediatR;
using System.Reactive;
using Unit = System.Reactive.Unit;


// ...
Unit a;
// or  System.Reactive.Unit a;
```

*[language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) also has its own `Unit` type... Is there any project that aims to unify the `Unit` type in .NET?*

Comment: Don't use MediatR ;) or ReactiveUI, your choice ;)

Comment: @Fabio but... but... I have to use them together...

Comment: It's an interesting question given the context but it's ultimately about names[paces]. Maybe the best, and worst, solution is to define your own `Unit` with implicit operators to and fro the various other types.

Comment: I think the solution you have is the cleanest available. Others would be to do fully qualified at the time of using the Unit type.

Comment: If you use ChiefTwoPencils solution consider naming it different so you don't have the conflict in names still. Eg you can use the implicit conversions then

Comment: @GlennWatson I am thinking of naming it `Void`, any suggestions for better name?

Comment: There's already a type `System.Void`, that is never used in C#, so probably a bad choice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.void?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I would recommend nicknames: `using RxUnit = System.Reactive.Unit;` and `using MrUnit = MediatR.Unit`.

Comment: @Shlomo yes... I just realized that.... Seems like there is no better choice other than `Unit` and `Void`? For sake of consistency, I would rather use one instead of using nicknames to differentiate between them two though.

Comment: I use `LanguageExt.Unit` (https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) a lot and besides having incompatible `System.Reactive.Unit` there is another -- IMHO bigger compatibility annoyance: There is `void` (and `Action`) built-in in C# which ideally would be replaced by some `Unit` type, too.


Unit should be a language feature built-in. Please go to https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1604 and add your comment / vote for comment / subscribe.